# The button or the text is not centered correctly

Tags: html, css

```css
html,body {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  height:100%;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-color: red;
  width: 700px;
}

.container {
  height: 90%;
}

.btn-outline-primary {
  color: black;
  border-color: black;
}

.btn-outline-primary:hover {
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: black;
}

.btn-outline-primary:onclick {
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: black;
}

.row-title {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.row-subtitle {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row-buttons {
  background-color: green;
}

.col-auto {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="jumbotron my-auto">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center row-title">
          <p>Very long text very long</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center row-subtitle">
        <p>Very long text very long</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center row-buttons">
        <div class="col-auto">
          <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#" role="button">Button1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#" role="button">Very long text very long</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#" role="button">Button3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Problem: button with text "Very long text very long" (blue) is clearly not aligned with the two `<p>` with text "Very long text very long" above it (green). What is the problem? It is like 5 px difference, but I don't understand why.

Comment: If you downvote, please at least comment why. I provided a minimal testable example and have a clear problem for which I cannot find solution.

Comment: Okay, I kinda figured out that adding `margin-left: 0px` for `row-buttons` solves the problem, but why?

Comment: It makes no sense to me what you try to achieve with your code, like do you want them to be in one line? Also if thats your goal your solution is 0 responsive.

Comment: idc about responsiveness, problem is that if you look at the button, it is like 5px off from the left compared to the two rows above it. Open in a full window to see what I'm talking about (snippet squishes everything)